# Loop through a file content and curl output to separate file

Tags: bash, loops, curl

I am still learning how to write bash scripts and need help with using a (For Loop) to run through a file with hundreds of server hostnames while using the curl command (`curl -i -k | grep -i ilo`) to output all ilo servers and their hostnames into a separate file. I really appreciate all your help!

Comment: A good place to start is [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide). If you have a concrete, specific question, ask it here, but see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

```
for url in `cat filename`; do echo $url >> newfile; curl -i -k $url | grep -i ilo >> newfile
```

Comment: randomir, the links are helpful. Thanks!